# How can I use PARAM for null variables?

Tags: powershell

I need to send information to my script via param, in some cases, all information must be added, if this condition is followed, the script works. If any information is missing, the script will give an error. I would like the script to ignore the missing information.

Example:

> script.ps1 -consultlog Application -id 1003 -level 4      (OK) 
>   script.ps1 -consultlog Application -level 4               (Fail)

```
param($consultlog,$id,$level)
$event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
   LogName= $consultlog
   ID= $id
   Level= $level
   StartTime=(Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
} 
$event
```

Comment: build your filter hashtable BEFORE you use it. [*grin*] that way you can test for valid data and remove the unwanted keys - very much like one can do with splatting ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey. Sorry, I'm a beginner in programming, thank you for the explanation but I'm still in doubt. Can you help me with this code?

Comment: sure! take a look at my answer ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_[edit - the version i originally posted use `.Where()` to filter the key/value pairs ... and gave a *dictionary* instead of a *hashtable.]*

you can add a test in the script to check for $Null inputs. it's rather like what can be done with splatting [`Get-Help about_Splatting`].

```
param ($consultlog,$id,$level)

# there is almost certainly a more graceful way to do this [*sigh ...*] 
$FilterHT = @{}
if ($consultlog) {$FilterHT.Add('LogName', $consultlog)}
if ($id) {$FilterHT.Add('ID', $id)}
if ($level) {$FilterHT.Add('Level', $level)}
$FilterHT.Add('StartTime', (Get-Date).AddHours(-24))

$event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHT

$event
```

if you call it thus ...

```
$FileName.ps1 -consultlog security -id 4624
```

... this version actually returns events. [*grin*] note that it handled leaving out the `-Level` parameter.

Comment: when I run the command this error message appears, it is related to the filterhashtable.

Get-WinEvent : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterHashtable'. Cannot convert value "System.Collections.DictionaryEntry" type 
"System.Collections.DictionaryEntry" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
No linha:14 caractere:40
+ $event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHT

Comment: @BryanAlmeida - arg! i had no matching ID items to test, so i _did not test the code properly_. [*blush*] the `.Where()` is the problem. let me fix that ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention.  I'll wait

Comment: @BryanAlmeida - try the new version ... i actually _tested it this time_. [*grin*]

Comment: Tested and approved!

Thank you very much for your patience in helping me.

Comment: @BryanAlmeida - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]